# detect only the candle without wick on top

Tags: mql4

My codes keep detect all candles with wick on top, how to make it detect only the candle without wick on top?

```
bool cond=close>open && high>close && high-close>open-low && high-close==0;
```

Comment: absolutely not clear what you need. `high>close` and `high-close==0` cannot be true at the same time

Answer (score 0):

bool cond=close>open&&high==close;

I think this is enough

Good luck !